# Do Anglophone and Francophone Canadians still have issues?

Tags: canada

A friend loaned me an old travel book about [Canada](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Montreal-Insight-Guide-City-Guides/dp/9624211353). One of the running themes inside the book is an uneasy tension between the Anglophones (the English) and the Francophones (the French) . It told of separatist movements till the 90's . Now could somebody tell/share how the situation is over there ?

Comment: Is that the 1990s?

Comment: apparently, at least according to the book, there was unsettled calm between the two at that point in time.

Comment: And every 4 years Texas demands to separate from the US. It's just something that happened enough times it's become an ingrained custom/joke amongst that particular culture. So yea, there's still the rift between Quebec and the rest of Canada but that rift is also simply just a part of Canadian culture.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quebec_sovereignty_movement#Modernization

Comment: Look forward to that.

Answer (score 2):

There are no tension between Québec (QC) and the Rest of Canada (ROC).

We are all a happy family.

There is no crime related to and or any political tension between QC and ROC.

Most hate crime these days are (unfortunately) racists and xenophobic and LGBTQ in nature.

I think the most newsworthy event was last winter in Quebec City: 
http://www.ctvnews.ca/canada/ctv-exclusive-sikh-man-viciously-attacked-in-quebec-city-1.2841809

The Federal govermnent and provincial government have mostly financial issues between them (Equalization payments) and political issues (separation of powers).

Health transfer between federal and provinces, most provinces (including QC) are together against the Federal government; so no real anglo/franco issue there.
http://www.cbc.ca/news/politics/health-negotiations-renew-1.3919802

Consumer protection law; federal government backs down after protest from QC.
(french) http://ici.radio-canada.ca/nouvelle/1005396/ottawa-retrait-article-projet-loi-c29-banques-protection-consommateur-quebec

Tar Sand Oil pipeline: No big issue there, anglo and franco and Natives in QC don't really want it and the ROC (mostly Alberta and Saskatchewan).
http://montrealgazette.com/business/energy/justin-trudeau-denis-coderre-meet-against-backdrop-of-energy-east-tuesday

and

http://www.nationalobserver.com/2016/01/22/news/brad-wall-provokes-anti-quebec-insults-over-pipeline-opposition

Mostly politicians having fun handling our money.

Most private people are nice towards the other group (french and anglos)

The independant party in QC is still not in power, and mostly likely will not be in power for the next few years (personal assesment of the situation) and polls in that regards puts the separation of QC of ROC  at around 30%.

(april 2016, and in the meantime, Pierre Karl Peladeau stepped down as independent party leader)

http://montrealgazette.com/opinion/columnists/don-macpherson-parti-quebecois-faces-dilemma-on-quebec-sovereignty-referendum

So come along, and have fun.

Comment: Evidence for all these claims please?

Comment: @user4012 are you asking me or Max ? For evidence of the issues, the Quebec Sovereignty Movement along with http://www.thecanadianencyclopedia.ca/en/article/francophone-anglophone-relations/ and http://world.time.com/2013/04/08/quebecs-war-on-english-language-politics-intensify-in-canadian-province/ to name two but there are plenty others.

Comment: @shirish - asking the author of the answer.

Comment: It is hard to have evidence for something that is not really there!